# How to solve diff. eq. involving function taking expression including itself as variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, function-and-relation-composition

$$
f(x)=f \left( x \pm \frac{l}{\sqrt{1+\dot{f}^2}} \right) \mp \frac{l}{\sqrt{1+\dot{f}^2}}\dot{f}^2,
$$
where $l$ is a constant. 
How is such a beast even approached? If anyone got intuition for educated guesses, I'm all ears.

EDIT 1:
I'm trying to find a container that, when turned with some constant angular velocity in any direction (rotational symmetry), will pour out the same amount of water per time, regardless of how much water is left in it (there must be some water in it though, of course). The expression in the main text is found by looking at a midsection of the container, where the outlines are given by $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$. I then say that the tangent to any point of $f$ is the surface of the water, and then I find the length $l$ between the point of the tangent and the point where the tangent intersects with $f(-x)$ (on the "back" of the container). If $l$ is constant, the flow of water will be as well.

EDIT 2: The question described in the first edit is fleshed out in [my more recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653719/does-this-container-exist) (which sadly doesn't yet have an answer).

Comment: It's not at all an educated guess but the function $f(x)=x$ solves the problem. Maybe this is a starting point.

Comment: @frog, thanks! Should I be worried, since $f(x)=x$ is not at all the function I'm looking for?

Comment: I don't know a smart way to proceed here but can you provide some context to the problem? Maybe it's an idea to look for solutions in special classes of functions. E.g. if you consider linear functions, only the function $f(x)\equiv 0$ and the identity solve the problem.

Comment: @frog, see edit in main text

Comment: @frog How do you get that $f=x$ is a solution?

Comment: @Siwel, x differentiated gives 1, so the equation becomes $f=x \pm l \mp l$

Comment: Ah yes I was reading it as the big bracket multiplying $f$, perhaps this should be made clearer by writing $f(x)$ on the LHS.

Comment: Even with context I feel unable to come up with a smart idea. One thing one might try to do is to use the implicit function theorem to solve (locally) algebraically for $f'$ (say around zero) and see if the new equation admits a solution using standard techniques. But I doubt this would give anything explicit.

Comment: hmm, I'm not familiar with how to use the theorem, how would one do that? I think it's pretty safe to assume that the container is flat in the bottom, i.e., $f'(0)=0$.. does that help?

Comment: You can define $F(x,y,z)=y(x)-y \left( x \pm \frac{l}{\sqrt{1+z^2}} \right) \pm \frac{l}{\sqrt{1+z^2}}z^2$. If you want to solve for $z$, the formal derivative $\partial_zF$ should be non zero and you get a short interval, where $z$ is expressed in terms of $y$ and $x$. You don't get anything explicit though. And still you would need to solve the resulting differential equation.